# Problems importing external CSS files on Codepen.io

Tags: css, pastebin

I love working with [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) and I'm trying to import a css file from [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Here is a link to my external file hosted on Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mj9dmzZw

and inside that file I link to my actual font files.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone point me in the right direction or let me know if this is even possible.

Here is the actual codepen. http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/CLitH

Inside the CSS section I have commented out the styling that I'm trying to include with the external CSS file. If you uncomment the styling for the iconfonts, you will see icons in the column 'Type'.

I have tried linking the flie in the settings of the css section that is built into codepen. And using the "@include url('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mj9dmzZw')" inside the css.

Comment: cant you just copy-paste the content of your http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mj9dmzZw  inside the CSS box in CodePen ?

Comment: Yes, Milche that will work. So that leads me to believe my file is correct. I"m trying to prevent my 'css' section on codepen from getting blasted with all this styling just for my iconfonts.

Comment: Maybe posting a link to your specific Codepen that doesnt work might help clarify the problem.

Comment: here is a link to the codepen. http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/CLitH If you uncomment the css, the icons will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on CodePen page, there is a small letter 'g' top-right of css input box.
You can import your .css there i think.

If you need some **.css** extension to your file for importation, just create a new file.css and @import your Pastebin css from within your new file.css

Comment: That is what i'm trying to do. I have the link to my pastebin css file inside the spot where you add 'External CSS File'. Codepen is accepting my link because they notify you if the link is invalid.

Comment: I've also tried to do a normal import inside the css section of codepen. [MyCodePen](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/CLitH) This isn't working with my file. Here is a link to the codepen where i'm trying to include the file via '@include url()' and by adding it thru the settings for css by clicking on the gear and pasting the link in the External CSS File input.